# How to prove that finite ordinals multiplication is commutative

Tags: set-theory

Given that $\alpha * 0 =0 $ and $\alpha * S(\beta) = \alpha *\beta + \alpha$

And we know that addition is commutative and associative.

My proof : Let $n,m \in \omega$ and i did double induction, but reached this point and could not solve.

I proved that $m*0 = 0*m = 0$

And assumed that $n*m=m*n$ and now i need to prove that $S(n)*m = m *S(n)$

Where $S(n) = n+1$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to prove $S(n) *m = n*m + m$ first, by induction on $m$

Comment: @Max you mean before i assume the second induction, or within the second induction ?!

Comment: @Ahmad You can't compare $S(n)*m$ and $m*S(n)$ if you don't know what $S(n)*m$ is. So you need to prove that it is $n*m + m$. Exactly when you choose to do it is somewhat irrelevant (I would probably do it as a lemma before I even start the proof that multiplication is commutative), but you can't proceed from where you are without it.

Comment: @Arthur i am really stuck, i reached another barrier, proving that $S(n) * S(m) = n* S(m)+S(m)$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Getting another question off the unanswered list.)

Let $n\in\omega$; you’ve already shown that $S(n)*0=0=n*0+0$. Now suppose that $m\in\omega$ is such that $S(n)*m=n*m+m$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
S(n)*S(m)&=S(n)*m+S(n)\\
&=n*m+m+S(n)\\
&=n*m+m+n+1\\
&=(n*m+n)+(m+1)\\
&=n*S(m)+S(m)\,,
\end{align*}$$

where I’ve freely used commutativity and associativity of addition. It follows by induction that $S(n)*m=n*m+m$ for all $n,m\in\omega$.

Now you have the tool that you need to show that if $n,m\in\omega$ are such that $n*m=m*n$, then $S(n)*m=m*S(n)$:

$$\begin{align*}
S(n)*m&=n*m+m\\
&=m*n+m\\
&=m*S(n)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Since you already knew that $n*m=m*n$ when $n=0$, you can conclude by induction that $n*m=m*n$ for all $n\in\omega$.